# Footer CSS Overflow issue

Tags: css

I'm new to css I created this footer, I have one problem here.
when I try to shrink it the tables disappear and bypass the screen borber and I want it to stay within the screen desired size, would love to know what I did wrong, Thank you.

note: I'm not trying to make it responsive yet I just want to be able to see all the content inside the screen borber.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>footer trial</title>
</head>
<body>

    <footer>
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="table1 tables">
                <h2 class="table-title">ABOUT</h2>
                <p class="about">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.<br> Odit impedit molestiae amet ab maxime saepe qui est<br>, temporibus voluptatibus eaque nihil, ut, omnis sit fugiat cupiditate explicabo. Repellat totam nisi incidunt.<br> Nulla nisi officiis ex, facilis delectus modi, dolor numquam consequuntur aspernatur,<br> harum autem perferendis iure ab! Praesentium, ea corrupti!</p>
            </div>
            <ul>

            <div class="table2 tables">
                <h2 class="table-title">INFORMATION</h2>
                <nav class="table-links">
                    <li><a href="#" class="table-link">table-link1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="table-link">table-link2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="table-link">table-link3</a></li>
                </nav>
            </div>

            <div class="table3 tables">
                <h2 class="table-title">CATALOGS</h2>
                <nav class="table-links">
                    <li><a href="#" class="table-link">table-link1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="table-link">table-link2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="table-link">table-link3</a></li>
                </nav>
            </div>

            <div class="table4 tables">
                <h2 class="table-title">SITEMAP</h2>
                <nav class="table-links">
                    <li><a href="#" class="table-link">table-link1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="table-link">table-link2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="table-link">table-link3</a></li>
                </nav>
            </div>

            <div class="table5 tables">
                <h2 class="table-title">CONTACT</h2>
                <p class="about">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.<br> Odit impedit molestiae amet ab maxime saepe qui est<br>, temporibus voluptatibus eaque nihil, ut, omnis sit fugiat cupiditate explicabo. Repellat totam nisi incidunt.<br> Nulla nisi officiis ex, facilis delectus modi, dolor numquam consequuntur aspernatur,<br> harum autem perferendis iure ab! Praesentium, ea corrupti!</p>
            </div>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <div>
        <a href="#" class="copyright"> all rights reserved 2022</a>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

CSS :

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;600&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}

body {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.footer {
    background-color: rgb(4, 97, 97);
    color: #fff;
    gap: 15rem;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:flex-start;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

ul {
    gap: 7rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:space-evenly;
}

.about {
    width: 400px;
    text-align: justify;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.table1 {
    margin-left: 5rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.table-title {
    color: rgb(4, 224, 151);
    line-height: 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.table-links {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2rem;
    font-weight: 400;

}

.table-link {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.copyright {
    background-color: rgb(5, 120, 124);
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    word-spacing: 0.24rem;

}
```

Comment: Please learn about the UL Element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul It cannot accept a `<div>` as child, only `<li>`

Comment: thank you for your answer, I turned it into this: https://pastebin.com/BjxqjgnH , the .footer is still the one controlling the flexbox and i'm running into the same issue

Comment: First of all your HTML structure is not good. You have `nav` tags and inside `li` tags. Please correct this, you should use `ul` with inner `li`. Then you overuse `flex`. Third, your `gap`s are too big. One more thing, you have `p` with a width of 400px. If you want the layout to be responsive, you shouldn't use such a fixed width.

Comment: @Azu Thank you, can you tell of the html structure was the reason behind the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it solve your problem, let me know if anything needed:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}

body {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.footer {
    background-color: rgb(4, 97, 97);
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.about {
    width: 400px;
    text-align: justify;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.table1 {
    margin-left: 5rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.table-title {
    color: rgb(4, 224, 151);
    line-height: 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.table-links {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2rem;
    font-weight: 400;

}

.table-link {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.copyright {
    background-color: rgb(5, 120, 124);
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    word-spacing: 0.24rem;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>footer trial</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <footer>
            <div class="footer">
                <div class="table1 tables">
                    <h2 class="table-title">ABOUT</h2>
                    <p class="about">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. <br> Odit impedit molestiae amet ab maxime
                        saepe qui est <br>, temporibus voluptatibus eaque nihil, ut, omnis sit fugiat cupiditate explicabo.
                        Repellat totam nisi incidunt.<br> Nulla nisi officiis ex, facilis delectusmodi, dolor numquam
                        consequuntur aspernatur,<br> harum autem perferendis iure ab! Praesentium, eacorrupti!
                    </p>
                </div>
    
                <div class="table2 tables">
                    <h2 class="table-title">INFORMATION</h2>
                    <nav class="table-links">
                        <li><a href="#" class="table-link">table-link1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="table-link">table-link2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="table-link">table-link3</a></li>
                    </nav>
                </div>
    
                <div class="table3 tables">
                    <h2 class="table-title">CATALOGS</h2>
                    <nav class="table-links">
                        <li><a href="#" class="table-link">table-link1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="table-link">table-link2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="table-link">table-link3</a></li>
                    </nav>
                </div>
    
                <div class="table4 tables">
                    <h2 class="table-title">SITEMAP</h2>
                    <nav class="table-links">
                        <li><a href="#" class="table-link">table-link1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="table-link">table-link2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="table-link">table-link3</a></li>
                    </nav>
                </div>
    
                <div class="table5 tables">
                    <h2 class="table-title">CONTACT</h2>
                    <p class="about">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.<br> Odit impedit molestiae
                        amet ab maxime saepe qui est<br>, temporibus voluptatibus eaque nihil, ut, omnis sit fugiat
                        cupiditate explicabo. Repellat totam nisi incidunt.<br> Nulla nisi officiis ex, facilis delectus
                        modi, dolor numquam consequuntur aspernatur,<br> harum autem perferendis iure ab! Praesentium,
                        ea corrupti!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
        <div>
            <a href="#" class="copyright"> all rights reserved 2022</a>
        </div>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```